# How to set upstream between local and remote branches?

Tags: git, github

I am learning git from book, but I struggle with some problems. I have to manually clone jquery repo. Below there are my commands.

```
git init 
git remote add origin https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
git fetch --no-tags origin main:refs/remotes/origin/main
```

I don't fully understand if it that fetch command is correct. jQuery has branch `main`, but after that I type following command:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/main
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: branch 'origin/main' does not exist.
```

I don't understand why is that. How to set upstream from my local master branch to the main branch in the remote repo of jQuery?

My git version: git version 2.35.1.windows.2

Comment: **I have to manually clone jquery repo** -- if you clone a repo, its easier to use [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone). also, what version git are you using? depending on the version, the syntax for upstream might be a little different, see [qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030) it may interest you - specifically the order of the branches.

Comment: I know that it is easier to use clone, but I try to understand that upstream and feel better how git works and I really don't know what is wrong with what I have done and why I can't set upstream that way. Basically I don't get it why git says that origin/main does not exist

Comment: Why do you want to set upstream at all? I basically never do. Also, why on earth would you set up a correspondence between local master and remote main? I mean, sure, you can, but you can do a lot of silly things. Just name your local branch main and make life easy.

Answer (score 2):

> `git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/main`

Wrong way 'round, and `--set-upstream-to` is for modifying an existing branch.

```
git branch -t master origin/main
```

aka

```
git branch --track master origin/main
```

and better might be

```
git checkout -b master origin/main
```

Easiest is just use upstream's name and `git checkout main`, Git will see the unadorned branch name and fire off its convenience checking. There's no `main` branch yet, so it'll look for a unique remote-tracking branch for it and find the one you set up.

```
$ git checkout main
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
Switched to a new branch 'main'
```